# prawnto and text format

Tags: plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn, prawnto

Prawn/prawnto is cool stuff to generate pdf file. But I am not able to render formatted text exactly as they are. Prawn is rendering all the html tags <b>, <i>, <p> as string. Below is the code i have written

pdf.text "#{@product.name}", :size => 20, :style => :bold
pdf.text "<b>Ashis Rai<b>"

and want to see the result as

```
Nokia N97  
Ashis Rai
```

but I am getting final result as below

**Nokia N97**
<b>Ashis Rai<b>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a below option that allows our formatted text to be render in pdf file

```
:inline_format => true
```

You can look over [How can I do inline formatting (bold and underline) for PDF generated by Prawnto in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929345/how-can-i-do-inline-formatting-bold-and-underline-for-pdf-generated-by-prawnto) by @Angela

Answer (score 0):

The pdf.text method will render what it is passed.  To make the text bold you need to use

pdf.text, :font_style => :bold

A good way to get the docs is to run 
**gem server**

Then point your browser to http://localhost:8808/doc_root/prawn-core-0.8.4/rdoc/Prawn/Text.html

This will give you more details on the methods and some of the options.