# How can I do inline formatting (bold and underline) for PDF generated by Prawnto in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

I generate a PDF file using Prawn and the Prawnto plugin in my rails application.

I create a standard form with a standard textarea, and submit that as the body of the PDF file.

However, I need to be able to format words and sentences with:

- bold
- underline
- maybe different type sizes

I want to be able to do it from within the textarea input box.  Right now, because I use prawnto, I basically am genering a view which outputs what is in the textarea.

But if I put, say, **bold** in the text area, it doesn't format, it just renders.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

we may have similar apps...

Prawn can do basic inline formatting based on (simple) HTML - take a look at the [text/inline_format.rb](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/blob/2acd1099fb0071bcd8954ee1ea291282ea6be254/examples/text/inline_format.rb) example on github.  In fact, take a look at the whole [Prawn Example Gallery](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/tree/master/examples) if you haven't - it's one of the best I've seen.

To get the HTML you need you can either type HTML straight into the textarea (a bit ugly - might not be a good idea if anyone besides you will be entering text) or use something like Markdown to interpret more user-friendly "style codes" like StackOverflow does.  I think [BlueCloth](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth) is the best-known ruby implementation, but I've never used it myself.

Bold and underline?  No problem.  Font size might be harder - I imagine it would be tricky to get BlueCloth to emit something like the (deprecated) < font > tag they use in the Prawn example...

Hope this helps - cheers!

Comment: so if I just add the inline_format => true it will take the HTML in the text area?

Comment: I am using the prawnto plugin, I forgot, and so not accessing the PDF directly, just passing a view with a render pdf and prawnto is taking care of it...how can I passformatting that way?

Comment: @Angela  I hadn't heard of prawnto.  I just checked it out, though, and it looks promising.  And it looks like it still uses the original Prawn methods, just in a view, so you should be calling `pdf.text @textarea_text` somewhere in your view.  Adding the `:inline_format => true` option like you said _should_ be all it takes.  But no promises - I haven't tested it!

Answer (score 3):

In response to bold text...

In controller:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf  {render :layout => false}
  prawnto :filename => @current_project+".pdf", :prawn => {:font => 'Times-Roman'}, :inline=>false     
end
```

Then in pdf.prawn file you can use:

in a text box:

```rb
pdf.text_box "Document Revisions", :size => 16, :style => :bold, :at => [0.mm,10.mm], :width => 100.mm, :height => 15.mm;
```

or in a line of text on its own:

```rb
pdf.text "Document Contents", :size => 16, :style => :bold;
```

As I understand it - but not tried it - to underline you need to do:

```rb
:styles => [:bold, :underline];
```

[reference this link for more](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.10.2/Prawn/Text/Formatted.html)

This is not a feature of version 0.8.4 but version 0.10.2 - not sure how you would do underline in 0.8.4. I am not currently using 0.10.2 so can not confirm that this is works.

Based on what you have said I think this is what you want to for bold:

```rb
pdf.text_box "#{@yourtext.text}", :size => 16, :style => :bold, :at => [0.mm,10.mm], :width => 100.mm, :height => 15.mm;
```

Comment: :styles => [:bold, :underline]; does not work in prwan 0.8.4 but is in latest version on github. so not sure which version you are using. I am using 0.8.4 and while :style => :bold works the others do not. Have edited answer to cover this and further question.